# Highlighting the currently active org-Babel block

Tags: org-mode, org-babel, highlighting

I want to do something similar to hl-line-mode but not sure if it has been implemented already and how it can be implemented.

The goal would be to set two color schemes for the #+begin and #+end lines or the entire block depending on whether the code block is active.

Comment: Is the notion of "active block" well defined? (I don't use Org.) If not, please specify what you mean by it.